# PHP Login Validation Issue

Tags: php, validation, authentication, modal-dialog

> This is my PHP validation code

```
    include 'core/init.php';

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
      $errors[] = 'Enter a valid username or password.';
    }
      elseif (user_exists($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'User does not exist.';
      }
      elseif (user_active($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Please activate your account first.';
      }
      else {

        if (strlen($password) > 32) {
          $errors[] = 'Password too long. <br>';
        }

        $login = login($username, $password);

        if ($login === false) {
          $errors[] = 'Incorrect username or password.';
        }
          else {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login; //login returns user_id  
            header('Location: hashtagphotowall.php');
            exit();
          }
        }

    //visual representation of error arrays
    //print_r($errors);

}
  else {
    if (empty($errors) === false) {
      $_SESSION['validation_errors'] = $errors;
      header('Location: login.php');
    }
  }
```

> This is my login form inside a modal

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 large-centered columns">

    <!--first modal form for login window-->
    <div id="firstModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">

          <?php if(isset($_SESSION['validation_errors'])): ?>
            <div class="validation_error_box">
              <?php output_errors($_SESSION['validation_errors']); ?>
            </div>
          <?php endif; ?>

      <p class="modal-row"><em>Sign In.</em><hr></p>
      <a href="#" class="button small">Connect with Facebook</a>
      <p class="hr-enclosed">or login with email</p>

        <form action="login.php" method="post">

          <div class="field-box">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username:" />
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password:" />
            <input type="submit" name="loginbutton" class="button small" value="LOGIN" />

              <?php
                function output_errors($errors) {
                  echo '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $errors) . '</li></ul>';
                }
              ?>
          </div>
        </form>

      <p class="modal-row-sub">forgot your password? get help <a href="#">here</a>.<br>
        new user? sign up <a href="#" data-reveal-id="secondModal">here</a>.</p>
      <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>

    </div>
```

> I cannot achieve my goal which is "to display validation errors in the same place where my login form is located. For example, under the submit button." Before I arrived with this code, my first code outputs an error but not inline with the login form. It displays errors on another web page. So I revised it so that I can show errors under input tags or under the field box itself. But what's happening now with my code was when I hit the login button, it redirects to another web page with no results. Just plain white page. I used the header('Location: login.php'); which is the place where my php validation is located. When I changed it to where my login form is which is login-modal.php (take note that I used proper calling of dir, whatever you call it), it redirects to another page with **NO** foundation framework and CSS. Just plain login form. And also **NO VALIDATION ERRORS DISPLAYED**.
>
> I am just a newbie with back-end web development so please bear with me. And also please help me. I have been stuck with this problem for long. Thank you. I highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Is there anything that could help me just by using Javascript? :(

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery for same page updation 'AJAX'. Simple PHP codeing will not be effective.
When you use simple PHP it will work for reload purpose while if you use jquery it will work for refresh.